# Mui theme direction with next.js 14

Tags: reactjs, next.js, material-ui, server-side-rendering

i'm currently have a provider for theme like this:

```
const Provider = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
    return (
        <AppRouterCacheProvider>
            <Rtl>
                <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>{children}</ThemeProvider>
            </Rtl>
        </AppRouterCacheProvider>
    )
}
```

and this is my Rtl component config:

```
const cacheRtl = createCache({
    key: 'muirtl',
    stylisPlugins: [prefixer, rtlPlugin],
})

function Rtl(props: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
    return <CacheProvider value={cacheRtl}>{props.children}</CacheProvider>
}
```

when im wrapping my app with rtl component im getting this error:
`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')`